# Is 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi band shared across routers?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bandwidth

When having a router with a 2.4 GHz connection, I understand from [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1760213/does-the-frequency-band-of-router-impact-network-speed) that it will be slower than a 5 GHz one, but I am confused on the following:

Is the 2.4 GHz more congested due to multiple devices operating in the same band connecting *to the same router*?
So only the specific household is affected?  Or is it that, e.g, in a case of an apartment building, the 2.4 GHz band is shared among adjacent apartments (floor above, floor below, next door, etc.), so there is congestion due to multiple devices connected to different routers?

Comment: 2.4 GHz band is shared across everything operating in this band, even microwave ovens.

Answer (score 14):

In broad, non-technical terms, it is congested because "everybody is talking at the same time".

Wifi, just like human conversation, isn't really directional, it spreads out around you, gradually fading out over distance, no matter who you are actually speaking to. When you speak, though you may be speaking only to your friend by your side, everybody else within a few yards can also hear you talking. Humans handle this quite well most of the time, only actually concentrating on the conversation they are joined in & ignoring all others.

WiFi has to do the same thing - all devices are simply 'speaking' out loud. Each WiFi access point has to decide if this communication was meant for them or someone else, then route the ones intended for them to the correct onward destination.

This means that the more 'talking' there is, the more decision-making needs to be done.

Similarly, if you and your friend are trying to have a conversation in a crowded place where many other people are talking at the same time, often you will miss what your friend said & have to ask them to say it again. Or you have two friends with you, both trying to tell you something different at the same time. You actually can't tell what either of them are saying; it's just too confusing to concentrate on both at once.

So with a wifi router. Signals can collide - two things speak at exactly the same time on the same frequency, so the router asks them to say it again. This wastes more valuable resources in an already over-crowded space.

Comment: But there is more than one frequency (channel). Wouldn't it all depend (on the number of routers, number of clients, their distance, etc.)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: It's also congested in the sense that the frequency is heavily over-used. Microwaves and baby monitors also transmit on this channel, and can completely screw up Wifi signals.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Except that there is a _lot_ of overlap between channels as well, and most APs auto-select exactly one of two channels, so about 80% of usage by WiFi is on exactly two specific channels.

Comment: It's not often I see EE information conveyed in both an accessible and accurate manner (the abomination that is the fluid analogy comes to mind as an example of the opposite). Sure there are more details than what you wrote but this gets the fundamentals across and Matija Nalis covered the next level quite nicely for those who want to know more. Well done.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to nice [Tetsujin analogy](https://superuser.com/questions/1760220/is-2-4-ghz-wi-fi-band-shared-across-routers/1760221#1760221), note that the **same sharing of spectrum happens with *both* 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz**.

However, as opposed to humans talking, there is actually **more than one** frequency in each standard (so-called "2.4 GHz" band actually uses up to 14 frequencies from 2.412 - 2.484 GHz). They're called "channels" (think about how humans can talk to each other on "one channel", while an ultrasonic dog whistle does not interfere with them, but it still transmits information to the dog, as it uses the "second channel")

The advantages of 5 GHz in handling such a shared spectrum are several:

- there are more independent channels in 5 GHz than in 2.4 GHz (where only approximately three non-overlapping conversations can happen at the same time), thus more devices can talk to one another without interfering (the result is there is less chance that your neighbor's Wi-Fi will be forced to use the same channel as you are, and thus there will be ***less chance of one having to wait for another***).
- the 5 GHz has a higher data coding rate, thus the same amount of data can be transmitted in a shorter time. This has the additional bonus that if there is a collision (because several devices tried to talk on the same channel in the same time), such noise will block the channel for a shorter amount of time, i.e., it ***will recover faster*** in case of a collision.
- the ***5 GHz is also noticeably worse at overcoming obstacles*** (like walls, etc.) than 2.4 GHz, which is actually an ***advantage for indoor use***—as your neighbor devices talking will be completely eliminated (or reduced to whisper) by the time they reach you, and thus won't bother your devices.

Comment: The frequency has absolutely nothing to do with how long it takes to transmit some amount of data, so your second point makes no sense. This is a somewhat common misconception, probably due to 802.11ac only being specified for the 5GHz band, so at one point you had to switch to 5 GHz to get the new higher data rates. However, both 802.11n and 802.11ax use the exact same set of coding rates for both bands.

Comment: @TooTea surely the same coding rate at a higher frequency = faster data?

Comment: @Tim No, the "frequency" refers to the *carrier frequency*, not the "frequency" with which you send a bit. The maximum coding rate is determined by bandwidth, not frequency.

Comment: Also note that the 3 non-overlapping channels from the original 802.11b spec can actually go down to just one or two with more recent standards which use wider channels.

Comment: @Tim There's a difference between bandwidth and carrier frequency. The bandwidth of WiFi may be roughly 10-160MHz, dependent on configuration and hardware.

Comment: You also miss another element why 5ghz is less crowded: There is less NON-WIFI stuff on it. From baby monitors to Microwave, all use the 2.4ghz channel so far - so not only do you have less capacity, but you also have devices totally ignorant about WIFI screaming in this band.

Comment: @TooTea thanks, I tried now to clarify/reword that carrier freq is different one from data coding frequency.

Comment: @TomTom  true about baby monitors and cordless phones (but hopefully not microwave ovens, which should be shielded), although the 5Ghz does additionally suffer from weather radar problems and disconnects / backoffs / renegotiations.

Comment: @MatijaNalis A lot of microwave ovens are unfortunately at least somewhat leaky. Not enough to be a problem for human health, and indeed usually not enough to cause interference over a longer range, but the sheer power difference does mean even a small leak will interfere severely with wireless communications in a localised area.